# Unable to switch branches. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, branch, git-reset

I'm probably missing something. Kindly point out my mistake.

I have a repository.
The trunk is called `master` (obviously) and contains a number of files.
I've created a branch called `dev-17` and added one more file (called `file17`) to that.

Now, on a Debian-based system I do:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 13e51c7 20150418.2030
$ git clean -f -d
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$
```

That looks good. And an `ls` shows all the files I expect.
Then I do:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/dev-17
HEAD is now at 145e638 add file17
$ git clean -f -d
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$
```

Doing an `ls` shows that the added `file17` is there indeed. So, apparently I'm on the `dev-17` branch. But, why does `git status` say that I'm on `master`?

Now for the real problem, *while on the `dev-17` branch* (EDIT: it appears that the above does not really take me to the dev-17 branch, so this statement is incorrect) this happens when I want to see if `file17` has changed:

```
$ git --no-pager diff --name-only dev-17..origin/dev-17 -- ./file17
fatal: bad revision 'dev-17..origin/dev-17'
$
```

Suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) **does not** switch branches. [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is the command you are looking for.

Comment: Why are you using `git reset --hard`, here? That's probably *not* what you want to do...

Comment: @Jubobs : I'm coding on another system and testing the changes on this one. I periodically use `git reset --hard` to maintain synchronised with the remote code. I think I mistook this command to (also) be able to switch between branches.

Comment: For the real problem: what does `git branch -a` give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to switch branches you donwt need to do reset. you need to `checkout` the desired branch

```
git fetch --all --prune
git checkout dev-17
```

This will checkout the **dev-17** branch

Comment: Mmm. This seems to work. Please explain why the `fetch` **before** the `checkout`? Would `git fetch origin` not accomplish the same?

Comment: Hi again. the --all flag will fetch **all** the branches + tags and not only the  current branch you are on right now. that's the difference.

Comment: the `--prune` will remove all the deleted branches/tags as well

Comment: OK. So, `git fetch ...` to (re-)download the repository. Then `git checkout <branch>` to have the correct set of files put in the working directory. Right?

Answer (score 1):

`reset` moves your current `HEAD` to the specified commit (and `--hard` updates the working files accordingly).

If your `HEAD` is `master` and you run `$ git reset --hard origin/dev-17`, you **move** `master` to the same commit as `origin/dev-17`. You are moving the reference to another commit, not only updating your local files. You are still on `master` as `git status` tells you, but `master` is now another commit (the same as what `origin/dev-17` points to).

To update the content of `origin/dev-17` with newer commits from your remote, use `git fetch origin dev-17`.

To update your local files to reflect the content of `origin/dev-17`, you need to `checkout` the branch `origin/dev-17`.

If you want to continue work on the branch, I'd advise to create a local branch on which to commit:

```
git checkout origin/dev-17
git checkout -b dev-17
```

After adding commits to the branch, you can push it back to your remote:

```
git push origin dev-17
```

(this will fail if additional commits were created/pushed to the remote while you were working locally. In that case you need to `pull` first, see below.)

---

Once you have set this up, making your local branch up to date is easy. What you want to do is:

```
git fetch origin dev-17
git merge origin/dev-17
```

and this can be done in one operation:

```
git pull origin dev-17
```

(assuming you are on your local branch `dev-17`)

Comment: Thanks for the info. FYI, I have no intention of commiting from the test machine. It just needs to remain in sync with whatever branch I have pointed it at. I was working on `master` and everything went fine. Then I wanted to do some testing with `dev-17` and the above happened.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly. As long as I stay on a given `$branch` I can use `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/$branch && git clean -f -d`. But if I want to switch to another $branch I need to use `git checkout -b $branch2` to make the switch and then continue on from there.

Comment: And HEAD (I now understand) is a pointer to a given commit in the history of the repository. And the files currently in the working directory reflect the state of the repo at that historical point.

Comment: Do not use `reset` at all. `HEAD` is a pointer to a given commit (the one you have checked out), correct. Actually, all branches are just pointers to given commits, even `master`. The purpose of `reset` is to move what your current branch points at. If you run `reset` while on `master`, you are changing the meaning of `master`! You do not want that. Again, `git checkout` the local branch that you want to update, then `git pull origin <the_branch_on_remote_to_update_from>`.

Comment: `checkout -b` is to **create** a new branch and check it out. To only switch to an existing branch, you need `git checkout` without flag.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Git CMD and run the following commands as required.

If your switching first time use: `git fetch --all`

If you trying to pull the recently created branch use: `git fetch`